# How do you price an option on fresh corn?

Tags: option-pricing, hedging, replication, commodities

I'm preparing for quant interviews, and I had this question for myself. I'm not actually trading corn options. My goal here is just to better understand how to deal with these kinds of options.

According to [this](https://www.foodnetwork.com/healthyeats/recipes/2009/08/in-season-corn), corn's "peak season lasts from May through September." Suppose corn is only picked May through September. In December of this year, someone (a warehouse?) would like to buy an option on fresh corn picked in June of next year.

According to Shreve's *Stochastic Calculus for Finance II*, the price of an option is derived from replicating the option by trading in the money market and the underlying asset. In December of this year, we cannot trade fresh corn that won't be picked until June of next year.

How do we replicate the option? If your answer depends on the existence of a market for other corn derivatives, what if these markets don't yet exist?

Comment: Wouldn't you hedge with the corresponding June futures (instead of the underlying)?

Comment: In the absence of a forward or futures market for June, you would not be able to hedge and hence I recommend not getting involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you should have a futures market, so you can hedge your option using the corresponding future. That is actually the right instrument to hedge and replicate, not physical corn picked in December. I imagine such a contract exists, but, for the sake of the exercise, let's assume it doesn't.

In the absence of a futures contract, you cannot fully replicate the option. You can still price it doing assumptions on the price dynamics and volatility, but, if you want to hedge, you will need to do proxy hedging, using a very correlated instrument. If you have the May contract, you can use that to hedge, and then as soon as the June contract starts trading, close your May position and open your June hedge.
Another possibility, if there is not a May contract yet, is to use a very correlated commodity (wheat, perhaps).